# Sending email from asp.net using Gmail SMTP OAUTH

Tags: c#, asp.net, email, network-programming

I just want to implement one sample mail sending application.
I have done lot of research for this. From all the corners I am getting same kind of solution. But that is not working for me.I am unable to find my mistake. I am using below code

```
protected void SendEmail(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string to = txtTo.Text;
    string from = txtEmail.Text;
    string subject = txtSubject.Text;
    string body = txtBody.Text;
    using (MailMessage mm = new MailMessage(txtEmail.Text, txtTo.Text))
    {
        mm.Subject = txtSubject.Text;
        mm.Body = txtBody.Text;
        if (fuAttachment.HasFile)
        {
            string FileName = Path.GetFileName(fuAttachment.PostedFile.FileName);
            mm.Attachments.Add(new Attachment(fuAttachment.PostedFile.InputStream, FileName));
        }
        mm.IsBodyHtml = false;
        SmtpClient smtp = new SmtpClient();
        smtp.Host = "smtp.gmail.com";
        smtp.EnableSsl = true;
        NetworkCredential NetworkCred = new NetworkCredential(txtEmail.Text, txtPassword.Text);
        smtp.UseDefaultCredentials = true;
        smtp.Credentials = NetworkCred;
        smtp.Port = 587;
        smtp.Send(mm);
        ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(GetType(), "alert", "alert('Email sent.');", true);
    }
}
```

And getting the exception like below

[image]

please suggest me how can I solve this issue.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Tried that proposed solution by doing turn off the "less secure apps" option from my gmail account it's giving same exception like I have mentioned above.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming that you are using a correct Gmail credentials for the account with which you are sending emails. You need to turn on "less secure apps" setting using the below link: https://www.google.com/settings/u/1/security/lesssecureapps

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. Yes it's working fine.But I have one more doubt by turning on less secure apps option won't it cause any security issues. Is is secured now?

Comment: It will not raise any security issues.
There is another way , you can create App in Gmail and use that App for sending emails.

Comment: Could you please give your suggestions to do that?

Comment: check out this link 
https://www.emailarchitect.net/easendmail/sdk/html/object_oauth.htm
let me know if you have any further query